# Seperation of Mball objects

Tags: modeling, objects

How can the Mball (small objects, modelled as clouds) be separated from the rest of the Mballs? There is an example of a newly spawned Mball which is separate from the others as indicated by the lack of selection (orange selection indication).

[image: Example of scene]

Comment: ... by name. I'm not sure what is the Q, so sorry if you asked something else ... Metaball's objects are sensitive on naming. There is always one "mother" and related "children" objects. Relation is set by the same name plus sequence number ... like "Mball" as mother and "Mball.001", "Mball.002" as children. For more details [see manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/metas/editing.html#conversion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new metaball system, you need to create a new metaball mother (or duplicate an existing metaball), and this new metaball needs to have a new prefix, but no suffix. For example create a new metaball, call it *New*, duplicate *New*, you'll have *New.001* and so on. The *New* balls will interact with each others but won't interact with the previous system, that has a different prefix.

If 2 metaballs don't interact and you want them to, you need to give the second one the same prefix as the first one.

Also note that if you delete the metaball mother it will delete the whole family  :((

Comment: Renaming the Mballs seperated it successfully, however the seperated Mballs lost their mesh leaving empty Mballs with no mesh generation. Changing values like "Resolution Viewport", "Render" and "Influence Threshold" does not update it.

Comment: make sure that you have a mother among the metaballs, i.e. one metaball that has no suffixe, is it the case?

Comment: My bad. I had the impression it would register as different if I repleaced the .002 with 2. Example: "Cloud", "Cloud.002" to "Cloud", "Cloud 2". Seems like the still counts as connected. Renaming it to "Cloud", "Cloud Testing" worked. Thanks.